# 2 column layout with full screen header

Tags: php, css, drupal

I am currently developping a website using Drupal where I have a navigation on top, below that the page content follows. With a header image followed by the content divided up into 2 columns.

The page content (besides of the navigation) is set into a wrapper with a max width to align the content in the middle. But I want this header image to be full screen followed by the page content in 2 columns back inside the wrapper. This layout only has to be applied to certain pages...

I read documentation on editing the template.php but nothing exact to provide a solid solution

I am using the following to provide a 2 column layout

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Display Suite fluid 2 column stacked template.
 */

  // Add sidebar classes so that we can apply the correct width in css.
  if (($left && !$right) || ($right && !$left)) {
    $classes .= ' group-one-column';
  }
?>
<<?php print $layout_wrapper; print $layout_attributes; ?> class="ds-2col-stacked-fluid <?php print $classes;?> clearfix">

  <?php if (isset($title_suffix['contextual_links'])): ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix['contextual_links']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <<?php print $header_wrapper ?> class="group-header<?php print $header_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $header; ?>
  </<?php print $header_wrapper ?>>

  <?php if ($left): ?>
    <<?php print $left_wrapper ?> class="group-left<?php print $left_classes; ?>">
      <?php print $left; ?>
    </<?php print $left_wrapper ?>>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($right): ?>
    <<?php print $right_wrapper ?> class="group-right<?php print $right_classes; ?>">
      <?php print $right; ?>
    </<?php print $right_wrapper ?>>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <<?php print $footer_wrapper ?> class="group-footer<?php print $footer_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $footer; ?>
  </<?php print $footer_wrapper ?>>

</<?php print $layout_wrapper ?>>

<?php if (!empty($drupal_render_children)): ?>
  <?php print $drupal_render_children ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I can't get my head around the following:

```
<div<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <!--  -->
  <header>
    <div class="navigation-container">
        <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
      <div class="l-header" role="banner">
        <div class="l-branding">
          <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-container" role="banner">
      <div class="l-branding clearfix">
        <?php if ($logo): ?>
          <div class="logo_vub"><a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" class="site-logo"><img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" /></a></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="language"><?php print render($page['language']); ?></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="l-main">
    <div class="l-content" role="main">
      <?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?>
      <?php print $breadcrumb; ?>
      <a id="main-content"></a>
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if ($title): ?>
        <h1><?php print $title; ?></h1>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php print $messages; ?>
      <?php print render($tabs); ?>
      <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
      <?php if ($action_links): ?>
        <ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($page['content_top']); ?>
      <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
      <?php print render($page['content_bottom']); ?>
      <?php print $feed_icons; ?>
    </div>

    <?php //print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
    <?php //print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>
  </div>


</div>
<div class="footer-container">
  <footer class="l-footer" role="contentinfo">
    <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
  </footer>
  </div>
```

Everything I apply in my 2 column layout gets 'printed' in the l-main div but how can I edit this so the group-header falls outside of this main wrapper and can be easily set to full with of the screen?

Comment: show us your effort that what you have tried so far ?

Comment: please provide your code, so we can have a look and play with...

Comment: Edited the question as requested